# Desktop sharing stopped working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: vino

Does anyone know how can I make vino-server to start running *again* via an ssh-shell command?

I've been using remote desktop with no issues up until today when I lost connection to the server and had to make someone to switch that computer off (power button because it has no screen). 
When it was turned back on I could open an ssh session but not a remote desktop session.
By executing `ps aux | grep "vino"` I found out vino-server is not running and can't make it to run via an SSH command line (I'm far away from that server), neither rebooting does the trick.

`dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino` reports

```
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['vnc']
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino enabled true
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

I already tried all the suggested solutions I could find, neither works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: `~/.Xauthority` was locked. I solved it by deleting via SSH these two files:

```
~/.Xauthority-c
~/.Xauthority-l
```

After reboot, vino-server started working again as shown by the command `ps aux | grep "vino"`